# AngularJS Error Code 401 handling without interceptors?

Tags: angularjs, angular-http, angular-http-interceptors, angular-http-auth

Following is the code I use, I get the Authentication Success Alert if the basic auth succeeds but the else alert "Authentication failed" is never displayed when the credentials are wrong. I do not use any routes and I don't have a need to use interceptors. Is there a way to get the 401 errors without using interceptors?

```
this.authorize = function(request, callbackFunc) {
  var encodedString = btoa(request.userName + ":" + request.password);
  var basicAuthString = 'Basic ' + encodedString;
  var requestObject = {
    location: '40005'
  };
  var req = {
    method: this.method,
    crossDomain: true,
    url: this.loginURL,
    data: requestObject,
    headers: {
      'Authorization': basicAuthString,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': '*/*',
      'apiKey': ''
    }

  };

  $http(req)
    .success(function(response) {
      callbackFunc(response, "success");
    })
    .error(function(response) {
      console.log("Error Received");
      callbackFunc(response, "error");
    });
};
```

In Controller:

```
$scope.Login = function() {

  AuthenticationService.authorize($scope.LoginRequest, function(response, responseCode) {
    if (responseCode === "success") {

      alert("Authentication Success");
    } else {
      alert("Authentication Failed");
    }
  });

};
```

Comment: does `console.log("Error Received");` getting printed

Comment: Nope. It doesn't go there either.

Comment: you mean to say error function inside the service doesn't get fire?

Comment: see here I can do the same thing which is not failing http://plnkr.co/edit/RlUTqN?p=preview showing "error" message properly

Comment: I have tried adding an intereceptor too

Comment: try to reproduce the problem in plunkr..

Comment: here is plunkr with your code..working proper http://plnkr.co/edit/eGPtiC?p=preview

Comment: did you able to reproduce issue with plunkr?

Answer (score 2):

As described in the [AngularJS documentation for $http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http), the $http call returns a promise with an error method, which has the code(number) of the status as one of it's parameters. You can check for a 401 status in there:

```
error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    if(status === 401){
        // Add your code here
    }
  });
```